# Не получается подключить БД sqlite, В чём проблема?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Ошибка заключается в том, что когда пытаюсь импортировать в терминале `db`, `from Main import db`
Получаю ошибку:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:SQLITE

С чем это связанно?

код:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'SQLITE:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    intro = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.id
```